# Вывод контента подкатегории. Иерархия страниц WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Сделал вывод категории на front-page.php нажимаю на категорию меня перекидывает на category.php где вывожу подкатегории (wordpress.com/category/masina/)(не сам контент этих подкатегории , а просто подкатегории тип к примеру lamborgini, audi...) и надо по нажатию на подкатегорию мне показывали контент(записи, которые в этой подкатегории). Меня перекидывает на wordpress.com/category/masina/lamborgini я понимаю , что сам контент должен быть на странице category.php но вот там только подкатегории и тут я подумал , а что если внизу сделать функцию вывода контента и перейдя в первый раз, чтоб показать подкатегории, он нечего кроме их не выведет , так как нечего выводить , а вот нажав на подкатегорию цикл вывода внизу файла на этот раз сработает и выведет контэнт внизу... такое может быть или надо как то по другому?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, почему нет, только на подкатегориях надо выводить не контент, а анонс, а при клике на заголовок или анонс - переходить на `wordpress.com/category/masina/lamborgini/post-name`, где уже показать полный текст записи. Это уже будет шаблон single.php

Comment: мне в том то и дело, что надо вывести только название подкатегории(никаких анонсов ,нечего не должно быть кроме подкатегории) а потом нажав на эту подкатегорию он меня кидает опять на category.php .. если создать single.php то будет перекидывать на single.php ? просто нажав на подкатегорию надо вывести все записи что  есть